# Laplacian of $|x|^\alpha$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, laplacian

I'm asked to compute the laplacian of
$$
  f: \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R},\; x \mapsto |x|^\alpha
$$

I know
$$
\begin{align*}
  \Delta f(x) &= \nabla \cdot (\nabla f) \\
  &= \nabla \cdot \begin{pmatrix}\alpha x_1 \left(f(x)\right)^{1 - \frac{2}{\alpha}} \\ \alpha x_2 (f(x))^{1 - \frac{2}{\alpha}} \\ \alpha x_3 \left(f(x)\right)^{1 - \frac{2}{\alpha}} \\ \vdots \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
$$

Calculating the laplacian for dimensions $n = 1 \ldots 4$ I noticed it to likely be
$$
  \Delta f(x) = \alpha (\alpha + (n-2)) \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \right)^{\alpha/2-1}
$$

Am I supposed to just partially differentiate each entry of the column vector with respect to $x_i$ and add up all the second order partial derivatives? (i.e. $\frac{\partial^2 f(x)}{\partial x_i \partial x_i})$

Comment: Yes just the $\partial^2f/\partial x_i^2$

Comment: Consider converting to polar coordinates...